# Повесить хук на событие "Обновить" в Страницы->Редактировать страницу

Tags: php, wordpress

Собственно надо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Обновить" в админке WP Страницы->Редактировать страницу срабатывала своя функция, которая проверяет, если post_id=XXX, тогда сохраняем файл.

В functions.php пишу...

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save' );
function save($post_id){
if ($post_id == xxx) {
....
```

Но ничего не происходит...

Или на какой хук повесить данную функцию?

Comment: Все правильно написано, должно работать. Ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: если вызывать функцию отдельно и передавать необходимый ID то все срабатывает, а вот хук нет!

Comment: даже если убрать if ($post_id == xxx) { .... поидее должно срабатывать при редактировании любой страницы в админке WP но файл не сохраняется

Comment: Могут стоять другие плагины, которые тоже используют этот хук. Попробуйте поставить приоритет 100, например. `add_action( 'save_post', 'save', 100 );`